# Iteration through nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, iteration

Let say I have dictionary in which the first key is phone number of caller, and the keys of second dictionary are phone numbers of recipients of the call, and the value is duration of phone call in seconds. I want to append in the same dictionary also phone numbers of the recipients of call as first key, than all numbers that were in contact with that number as the keys of nested dictionary, and duration of all calls for every of those numbers as value. Also if the key of nested dictionary is already first key of dictionary, it should add duration of phone call, on the existing duration Actually, I want a 'phone list dictionary' in which is noted for every phone number that appears, with whom he was talking and how long was conversation with that person.
How my dict looks like:

```
dict={'123456789': {'132456789': 583, '123546789': 444, '257918896': 528, '111111111': 495,}, '296358741': {'132456789': 631, '123456789': 98, '456789123': 395}, 111111111:{'123456789':150}}
```

How I want it looks like(when I put + I thought that result of this operation should be value :

```
dict={'123456789': {'132456789': 583, '123546789': 444, '257918896': 528, '111111111': 495+150,'296358741':98}, '296358741': {'132456789': 631, '123456789': 98, '456789123': 395}, '132456789':{'123456789':583,'296358741':631},'111111111':{'123456789':495+150}, '296358741':{'123456789':98}, '456789123':{'296358741':395}, '123546789': {'123456789':444}, '257918896' :{'123456789':528}}
```

I have tried this:

```
for k in dict:
    for called in dict[k]:
        if called not in dict:
            dict[called]={k:dict[k][called]}
        else:
            if k in dict[called]:
                dict[called][k]+=dict[k][called]
            else:
                dict[called]={k:dict[k][called]}
print(dict)
```

But it doesn't work, and output error:**RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration**. Is there any easier way to do this. I am very beginner, I have searched previous posts about iteration trough nested dictionaries, but I couldn't find anything that I can apply here.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its never a good idea and more often than not impossible to change the structure of an iterable entity WHILE iterating through it. Many unanswerable questions arise about how the iterator should handle those changes. What you can do is create a new iterable entity (in this case a brand new dict, where you add each (key, value) item as you iterate:

```
new_dict = {}
for caller, call_log in dict:
    new_dict[caller] = call_log 
    for receiver, duration in call_log:
        new_dict[receiver] = {caller: duration}
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it still doesn't work. I get this error:    for caller, call_log in dict:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Sorry, posted answer late at night so brain had clocked off. Add ".items()" tp both for loop lines. ie - for caller, call_log in dict.items(): - and - for receiver, duration in call_log.items():